# parametrize ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

i'm using single ajax method all over my site and i need to parametrize all params and options, also callback methods (success,beforeSend,error, etc ..)

for now i wrote:

```
function ajax(_type,_url,_data,_dataType,_starter,_callback_success,_callback_error, etc ..){
    $.ajax({
        type:_type,
        data:_data,
        dataType:_dataType,
        url:'http://localhost:9292/'+_url,
        success: _callback_success,
        error: _callback_error,
        // etc ...
    });
}
```

after that i would like to use this method in this way for example:

```
ajax(
   'GET',
   users,
   {},
   'json',
   false,
   function(){
       alert(json);
   });
```

i don't know how can i parametrize statuses (success,error,BeforeSend)? i'm trying with simple vars _callback_error or _callback_success but it's not clear to me how to pass callbacks in statuses

hope is clear my question

Comment: You're not clear at least to me. **Update:** (and for the upvoters of the comment...)

Comment: I think you forgot to include your question.

Comment: It's still not clear, the edit didn't do the trick. :( anyway what is the purpose of this function, you can call the `ajax` function instead of this function...

Comment: @gdoron right hope is clear now )

Comment: @gdoron mmm... i would like to use this method allaround the site

Comment: Why, when you can use $.ajax all around the site?

Comment: @Eli cause anytime i need to specify type,dataType,data,etc etc ... 5 $.ajax = 100 lines of code 5 personal methods = 70 lines of code

Comment: Well, there's 15 minutes of my life I'm never going to get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery will pass those into the callbacks when it invokes them.

```
function ajax(_type,_url,_data,_dataType,_callback_success, _callback_error){

   $.ajax({
        type:_type,
        data:_data,
        dataType:_dataType,
        url:'http://localhost:9292/'+_url,
        success: _callback_success,
        error: _callback_error
    });
}
```

Here's an example usage of your function.

```
ajax('POST', '/test.php', {}, 'json', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        // if request succeeds this callback will be invoked
    }, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
       // if request fails this callback will be invoked
    }
});
```

Comment: what if i need to use callbacks in error,success and beforeSend status? as i can see i can pass only 1 textStatus ...

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function name to success and error:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJ8Xm/

```
function mySuccess(data) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function myError(err) {
  alert(err);   
}

ajax("jsonp", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", { q: "cats", v:"1.0" }, "jsonp", "", mySuccess);

function ajax(_type,_url,_data,_dataType,_starter,_callback_success,_callback_error){
    $.ajax({
        type:_type,
        data:_data,
        dataType:_dataType,
        url:_url,
        success: _callback_success,
        error: _callback_error
    });
}​
```